# Load google map failed

Tags: c#, google-maps, c#-4.0

In my a c# program, I want to load a google map which is a html file stored in my local disk but it failed.It says that the application have something wrong with internet connection. Here is my  screenshot and some code

```
  private void 加载地图ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //webBrowser1.Navigate("D:/GoogleMap/GoogleMap.html");
            webBrowser1.Navigate("D:/exercise/源代码/windows监控端/TestGoogleMapGps/TestGoogleMapGps/GoogleMap.html");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well normally your local machine uses the backslash, not the forward slash, so try:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"D:\GoogleMap\GoogleMap.html");
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"D:\exercise\源代码\windows监控端\TestGoogleMapGps\TestGoogleMapGps\GoogleMap.html");
```

Although, I'm not entirely sure that's the solution you're going for.

Comment: Do i need to change my path which store the googlemap.html file with your approach?

Comment: If you end up running this code on a live webserver than you most likely will want to give the URL path to the file.

Comment: Exactly what I see wrong, since its on a local filesystem, the path needs to be D:\folder\folder\myfile.html 

And, string literals with @ is the other glaring problem, otherwise your browser is receiving a string that looks like:
        D:xercise代码indows监控端estGoogleMapGpsestGoogleMapGpsoogleMap.html